# implementation recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

I am still very new to recursive and I want to return 3 from this array `int arr[size] = {21, -6, 3, 5, 5, -3, 6, -21}` for having same absolute value with recursive implementation.

However, I get the value 0. I cant pinpoint out what is making this program not bringing desired value.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int additive_inverse_opposite_pairs_count(int* arr, int n) {
  int size = n;

  if (n == 0) {
    if (arr[n] == -1 * arr[size - 1 - n])
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
  } else {
    int count = additive_inverse_opposite_pairs_count(arr, n - 1) + count;
    if (arr[n] == -1 * arr[size - 1 - n]) {
      count += 1;
    } else
      count = 0;
    return count;
  }
}

int main() {
  int size = 8;
  int arr[size] = {21, -6, 3, 5, 5, -3, 6, -21};
  int value = 0;

  value = additive_inverse_opposite_pairs_count(arr, size);
  cout << "value: " << value << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the expected return value for the function? Have you tried testing whether your function works for the simplest cases, e.g. lists of size `0`, `1`, `2`?

Comment: `int count = ... + count;` uses `count` before it's initialized and has undefined behaviour. I suspect that you intended to "share" the value of `count` between function calls, but recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions; local variable are local to a specific function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are accessing `arr[n]` where `n` is the size of the array. The valid indicies of an array are `0..n-1`, so you need to change `arr[n]` to `arr[n-1]` in the `else` part of your `if` statement.

One idea is to simply start at an index `i`, scan the rest of the array from that point on for the additive inverse, and if it is found, return that number, otherwise recurse further into the array. I wrote a helper function to do the work.

```c++
int helper(int* arr, int i) {
  if (i == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if (arr[i] == -arr[j]) {
      return abs(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return helper(arr, i - 1);
}

int additive_inverse_opposite_pairs_count(int* arr, int n) {
  return helper(arr, n - 1);
}
```